# Voting mutually duplicates

Tags: support, closed-questions, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

Today I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/1993650) in the close vote review queue, which was flagged as exact duplicate of another question. Paradoxically, [the possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209881/php-sessions-switch-image) was closed because it was a duplicate of the question that was being voted to be closed.

Obivously, one of them is an exact duplicate of the other one, but in my opinion it doesn't make sense that both should be closed because they are mutually duplicates.

Shouldn't this situations be automatically detected by the system, so you can vote only one of this question as a duplicate of the other one?

*Edit:*

It looks like this new user is a bit impatient, because [this is the third time he asks the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194700/php-imageswap-script-stuck). However, in that case the next two times he has asked it they should be closed as duplicates of the original one instead of between them.

Here it is [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2069147), this one with only two questions: [Jigsaw Puzzle Solver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427627/jigsaw-puzzle-solver) (first one to be asked) and [Jigsaw Puzzle Solver Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428145/jigsaw-puzzle-solver-method).

Comment: Something tells me that user is not going to be around for very long

Comment: +1 I saw this too and skipped not knowing how my closure vote might end in a circular reference of doom.

Answer (score 4):

The second question isn't *just* closed as a duplicate of the first (which would be a true circular reference).  It's closed as a duplicate of that first question *and another answered open question*.  So while yes, technically, there is a circle, there is a way out of the circle too.

Should the be fixed?  Meh, it certainly could be.  I don't think it's advantageous to have it in this state, but as someone is still capable of getting from either question to an open duplicate of that question I'm not exactly worried about it not being fixed either.